# How to remove automatic width assignment in \includegraphics from Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm using Rmarkdown to create pdf files. I have chunks inside the .Rmd file like this one:

````
```{r}
knitr::include_graphics('image.png')
```
````

This is converted in the .tex file to:

```
\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\NormalTok{knitr}\OperatorTok{::}\KeywordTok{include_graphics}\NormalTok{(}\StringTok{'image.png'}\NormalTok{)}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\includegraphics[width=8.88in]{image}
```

Unfortunately, in most cases that I've seen the width is not appropriate. How to automatically remove the "[width=8.88in]" ?  On an other computer the width was not set like this, even with the same .Rmd file, and the images had the appropriate size.
But I cannot figure where this difference comes from, as I do not have access to this computer anymore.

Thank you

Comment: You could just use a different command such as i) a direct markdown include or ii) the latex command `\includegraphics{file}` or presumably also iii) just set fig.width as a knitr chunk option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the argument `dpi` on the help page `?knitr::include_graphics`. In short:

```
knitr::include_graphics('image.png', dpi = NA)
```

Or manually specify a width via the `out.width` chunk option.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you have any idea why I didn't had to specify this setting on an other computer? Could it be related to the pandoc version or the Rmarkdown package version?

Comment: No, it is most likely to be due to the existence of the **png** package (if it is installed, the automatic width will be calculated).